# Reset the value to the configuration "spark.executor.instances"

Tags: apache-spark

We have a YARN cluster and we use Spark 2.3.2 version. I wanted to use Spark's dynamic resource allocation while submitting the spark applications but in the spark-defaults.conf file the value of the property `spark.executor.instances` is set to 16. From my understanding, I should not set `spark.executor.instances` if we wanted to use dynamic resource allocation. Otherwise, even if the dynamic resource allocation is enabled, it is getting overridden by the property `spark.executor.instances`.

I can't edit the spark-defaults.conf, so I wanted to reset the value assigned to `spark.executor.instances` through the `--conf` argument to spark-submit. I tried setting it to blank or 0 but in both of the cases, the job failed with `spark.executor.instances` should be a positive number.

Given this situation, how can I successfully use Spark's dynamic resource allocation?.

One more observation is, I do not see that the dynamic resource allocation enabled in the spark-defaults.conf file. Isn't it a default property since Spark 2.0?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to reset the configuration `spark.executor.instances`. If dynamic resource allocation is enabled as well as if we set `spark.executor.instances`, then the parameter `spark.executor.instances` is used to calculate the initial number of executors required

`initial executors = max(spark.executor.instances,spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors,spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors)`

As long as we set either `spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors` or `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` more than `spark.executor.instances`, The configuration `spark.executor.instances` does not have any impact on the dynamic resource allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the dynamic allocation here

https://dzone.com/articles/spark-dynamic-allocation

This will give you a brief idea of how it works.